# Ionic 2 Firebase initializeApp & onAuthStateChanged slow

Tags: android, ios, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm working on my first Firebase app with Ionic and I'm having some issues with my login code. From my browser I see no issues but once I install the app on to a phone(iOS & Android) the login takes about a minute because the callback from onAuthStateChanged takes a long time. I'm using `"firebase": "^3.8.0".` I added the code I'm using to login. Any ideas on why Firebase is choking?

`app.component.ts`

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, private statusBar: StatusBar) {
    this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    let config = {
      apiKey: "***",
      authDomain: "***",
      databaseURL: "***",
      storageBucket: "***",
      messagingSenderId: "***"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    this.authData = new AuthData();
    this.zone = new NgZone({});
    const subscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log("onAuthStateChanged");
      this.zone.run(() => {
      console.log(" zone onAuthStateChanged");
        if (!user) {
          this.rootPage = LoginPage;
          subscribe();
        } else {
          // this.rootPage = HomePage;
          this.rootPage = EditProfile;
          subscribe();
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: 3.9.0 was launched today with the fix for this: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#3.9.0 You should no longer be getting this error.

Comment: @bojeil thanks!! I'm going to update this guy asap and see if it works

Comment: I'm using 4.10.1 and after logout/login `onAuthStateChanged` takes 4 seconds consistently in my tests. Is this common?

Comment: Make sure you're using the command line --release --prod flags when you deploy your ionic app. This turns on the Ahead of Time Compiling for Ionic. This might shave down the lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced with the same issue.
After some research I found that this issue comes with firebase "**3.8.0**".
Downgrade to **3.6.6** solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to firebase 3.9.0 in your project, solves the issue for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The update 3.8.0 slowed down the authentication on Ionic 2 devices. Here is the discussion about it in this [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/11290#issuecomment-296212847) and the solution by the firebase team untill they fix it [google docs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/svgk3GNcY0o) in the new patch.